# Parsing JSON into Object

Tags: c#, json

Trying to get the result from a webservice call to return a Model. I eep getting the error:
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'CI.Models.Schedule' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

```
public Schedule getCourseSchedule()
{
    var obj = new
    {
        States = new[] { new { State = "MX" } },
        Zip = "",
        Miles = "",
        PaginationStart = 1,
        PaginationLimit = 3
    };
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "apoplication/json";
        var url = "http://192.168.1.198:15014/ShoppingCart2/CourseSchedule";
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        byte[] result = client.UploadData(url, data);
        string returnjson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
        Schedule sched = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Schedule>(returnjson);
        return sched;
    }
}
```

Schedule Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Globalization;

namespace CI.Models
{
    public class Schedule
    {
        public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }

    public class Course
    {

/*
JSON Data returned from web service:        
{
   "ProgramGroup":"MR",
   "ProgramCode":"RM",
   "EventCode":"20160901MXMR",
   "FormalDate":"September 1-2, 2016",
   "StartDate":"2016\/09\/01",
   "Price":5,
   "LocName":"WB Hotel",
   "LocAddress":"Av. Speedy Gonzales 220",
   "LocCity":"Monterrey",
   "LocState":"MX",
   "LocZipCode":null,
   "LicenseeURL":null,
   "AgendaURL":"NA",
   "SeatsAreAvailable":"2",
   "GeneralInfoHTML":"General Info goes here.",
   "GateKeeperHTML":null,
   "EventType":"SS",
   "TotalCourses":3
}
*/
        public string ProgramGroup { get; set; }
        public string ProgramCode { get; set; }
        public string EventCode { get; set; }
        public string FormalDate { get { return FormalDate; } set { FormalDate = convertFormalDateToSpanish(value); } }
        public string StartDate { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string LocName { get; set; }
        public string LocAddress { get; set; }
        public string LocCity { get ; set; }
        public string LocState { get; set; }
        public string LocZipCode { get; set; }
        public string LicenseeURL { get; set; }
        public string AgendaURL { get { return AgendaURL; } set { AgendaURL = buildAgendaLink(value); } }
        public string SeatsAreAvailable { get; set; }
        public string GeneralInfoHTML { get; set; }
        public string GateKeeperHTML { get; set; }
        public string EventType { get; set; }
        public int TotalCourses { get; set; }

        public string convertFormalDateToSpanish(string val) 
        {
            DateTime TheDate = DateTime.Parse(StartDate);
            string[] FormalDate = val.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
            string _Date = FormalDate[1].Replace("-", " al ").Replace(",", "");
            string _Month = ci.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TheDate.ToString("MMMM", ci));
            val = string.Concat(_Date, " ", _Month);
            return val;
        }

        private string buildAgendaLink(string val)
        {
            if (val.Trim() != "")
            {
                val = string.Concat("<a href=\"/pdfs/", EventCode, "_Agenda.pdf\">Agenda</a>");
            }
            else
            {
                val = "Agenda";
            }
            return val;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: You should post the actual data received from the web service. Set a breakpoint at the line where you are about to deserialize and post actual contents of `returnjson`.

Comment: Btw, it looks like `FormalDate` and `AgendaURL` accessors will cause a stack overflow. You should use real backing fields in these `get`/`set` methods. Additionally, it is uncommon for a getter to return a different value than one set through a setter. So, even better idea would be to make these properties auto-implemented like all other and create separate read-only (i.e. `get`-only) properties which return "processed" values. That way you could serialize, deserialize and serialize again the object and it would have correct values.

Comment: @Groo, I'm not following you, can you post a link to some examples?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server returns an array. Just try

```
Course[] courses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Course[]>(returnjson);
```

Comment: @MB34 I updated the answer, Let's give another shot. (It is hard to try to help blindly without knowing the *real* json)

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is not an answer to your original problem, but I added it like an answer in order to explain my comment above with some actual code.

First problem with your code is that `FormalDate` and `AgendaUrl` properties simply won't work. Accessing them will result in a `StackOverflowException`, because you basically defined them recursively.

A property is merely syntax sugar for two separate getter/setter methods, so by writing this:

```
public class Course
{
    public string FormalDate
    {
        get { return FormalDate; }
    }
}
```

You are basically writing this:

```
public class Course
{
    public string GetFormalDate()
    {
        // recursive call, with no terminating condition,
        // will infinitely call itself until there is no
        // more stack to store context data (and CLR
        // will then throw an exception)
        return GetFormalDate(); 
    }
}
```

To fix that, you need to add an actual *backing field*, e.g.:

```
public class Course
{
    private string _formalDate; // <-- this is a backing field;

    // and this property uses the backing field to read/store data
    public string FormalDate 
    { 
        get { return _formalDate; } 
        set { _formalDate = convertFormalDateToSpanish(value); } 
    }
}
```

Additionally, it's unusual for a property getter to return a different value than the one set through a setter. In other words, I would never expect this from a class:

```
var course = new Course();
course.StartDate = "2016/09/01";
course.FormalDate = "September 1-2, 2016";

Console.WriteLine(course.FormalDate); // prints "1 al 2 Septiembre" ?
```

I would rather move this functionality into a different class, or at least create different properties which return these values:

```
public class CourseInfo
{
    // this is now a "dumb" auto-implemented property
    // (no need for a backing field anymore)
    public string FormalDate { get; set; }

    // this read-only property returns the converted value
    public string LocalizedFormalDate
    {
        get 
        {
            return convertFormalDateToSpanish(FormalDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Looks like I have some more learning to do with C#. I come from a Delphi and PHP background and you can do that in both.